# Spark: rewrite .filter("count > 1") without string expression

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

There is a piece of code in Java:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = ...
...
dataset.groupBy("id").count().filter("count > 1");
```

Is there a way to set `"count > 1"` condition using some dataframe methods, something like `filter(count().gt(1))`?

Answer (score 1):

Function "col" has methods for comparison, them can be used:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
ds.filter(col("count").$greater(lit(1)))
```